# Visual Basic 6.0 +Sql Server Stored procedure Timeout issue

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb6

Sir,
I am using vb6.0 and sql server 2005. I wrote a small procedure and it return immediate result in sql server but in vb 6.0 it return timeout. Any idea for any body? Please help?

My Procedure:

```
Alter procedure
[dbo].[SpRptSalesDayBookSummary](@liComid integer,@liPerid integer,@ad_dtfrm DateTime,@ad_dtto DateTime)
AS
begin   
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Select SaleDate,Sum(Grand) as tot
from SalesMaster a,SalesDet b 
Where a.id=b.RefId 
    And a.CompanyId= @liComid 
    And a.PeriodId=@liPerid  
    And a.SaleDate Between @ad_dtfrm And @ad_dtto
Group By SaleDate Order By SaleDate 
End
```

My vb code:

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rs1 As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim param2 As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim param3 As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim param4 As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim param5 As ADODB.Parameter

    g_objData.DBConn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = g_objData.DBConn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "SpRptSalesDayBookSummary"
    Set param2 = cmd.CreateParameter("Input", adInteger, adParamInput)
    cmd.Parameters.Append param2
    param2.value = 20
    Set param3 = cmd.CreateParameter("Input", adInteger, adParamInput)
    cmd.Parameters.Append param3
    param3.value = 8
    Set param4 = cmd.CreateParameter("Input", adDate, adParamInput)
    cmd.Parameters.Append param4
    param4.value = Format(PD_DtFrm, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Set param5 = cmd.CreateParameter("Input", adDate, adParamInput)
    cmd.Parameters.Append param5
    param5.value = Format(PD_DtTo, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    Set rs1 = cmd.Execute
```

Please help.

Comment: are you sure you are not getting lock-up in SQL? (use sp_who to find out).

Comment: It looks like you are setting the value to param after adding the param to the command object. try setting the value to param first (param.value = 20 etc) and then add it to the command object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the .CommandTimeout property is against the Connection object but you may need to up it.  I'm sure you can also specify the .CommandTimeout property against the command object too - try setting it to 600 (10 minutes).

I've seen code before that sets the CommandTimeout property against a connection in seconds, thinking it's minutes!